# Find all templates that are using a specific TBB?

Tags: web8, tbb

Is there a way for you to find all references of a TBB used in your SDL Web solution?

I've got a legacy TBB that I wanted to update and wanted to know which templates would be affected.

What I've tried so far:

- Used SDL Web Advanced Search by searching for the snippet of the TBB's TCM id
- Checked Where Used for a TBB

If possible, I'd like to do this without using Core Services.

Comment: If you don't want to use the Core Service for detailed reporting, then I'd have suggested using 'Where Used'. You say that you've done this already. What additional functionality/information is missing from this screen that you need?

Comment: Apologies. Please ignore the question. It was a red herring. The legacy TBB that I was searching for is not used but is referenced by text in the logs which was where the confusion came from.

Comment: Excellent. I’m glad that the mystery is sorted anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

I just want to point out that retrieving "where used" from GUI or Core Service is completely the same. So, it wont give you any additional information. The only additional thing that you can do is go through all your custom code and check if anything is programmatically reading your TBB for whatever purpose.